# Why copy right is not showing after adding custom footer in custom theme magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

> Please check the code below default.xml.Here i am using luma as parent theme.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo.jpg</argument>
                <argument name="logo_alert" xsi:type="string">Ashmolean</argument>
                <argument name="logo_ing_width" xsi:type="number">354</argument>
                <argument name="logo_ing_height" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="false"> </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="false" />   
            <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />        
            <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         
            <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="false"/>  
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>


        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="catalog.topnav"/>



        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" >
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.line" template="Magento_Theme::html/headersitemenu.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- <move element="copyright" destination="footer-container" after="footer"/> -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>` ? you should add it inside :

```
<container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">...</container>
```

something like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
    <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Or:

```
<move element="copyright" destination="footer" after="footer_links"/>
```

Comment: from where i need to copy copyright.phtml.In vendor is it available

Comment: If the `copyright` block is well added in Vendor, try to move it with `<move...`, also if it doesn't work, try to add the whole block `<referenceContainer name="footer-container">...` in your layout.xml theme file

Comment: thanks prince it works but added custom footer

Comment: You're welcome, If you don't need that footer you have to remove it, `<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`